# How to pass laravel/PHP function to JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, highcharts

I have a highcharts pie chart, Where i want put laravel's `route()` helper function.

I have the following code, Which

```
data: [{
    name: 'Car',
    y: 56.33,
    sliced: true,
    selected: true,
    url: {{route('dashboard')}}
}]
```

Which throws `SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{'`.

What is the best way to pass `PHP` variable to `JS`.

Comment: You missed a `]` after your variable. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: That's was a mistake here in the question, Its correct there !

Comment: Is the extesion of your view `.blade.php`?

Answer (score 4):

```
data: [{
   name: 'Car',
   y: 56.33,
   sliced: true,
   selected: true,
   url: "{{route('dashboard')}}" // note: surround with double quote
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open script tag (top or end of your Blade template) and pass your data to JS script.

I usually use `@stack`. Your code should be like this:

master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>

    Blah Blah Blah
    <!-- Start Content -->
    @yield('content')
    <!-- End Content -->


    <!-- Custom Scripts -->
    @stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

chart.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    Your Page Content
@endsection

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        var pie = {
            data: [{
                name: 'Car',
                y: 56.33,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true,
                url: "{{route('dashboard')}}"
            }]
        };
    </script>
@endpush
```

By this way, your data will be replaced with Laravel helper functions.